# Windows app to take a link after being opened

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to send my users a link that would take them to an exact spot in my application.

This is a windows WPF application.

I can do this by registering with windows, so it starts the application, and gets the parameters on startup, but I want to load it into an existing application instance, and not start a new one.

**My problem is how to do it when the application is already started?**

I would need an event, instead of just args from the main method. It's running and you click on a link, and the app needs to handle it. Already started, so the main args is not an answer.

**Potential Solution:**
I can make another executable that is registered with windows instead. This would take the data and send it to the main app via (whatever you prefer, a Q, named pipes, etc..). I can then define the transport and it would be supportable, but then I would have this secondary EXE sitting out there.

While I believe it will work it seems like quite a workaround (hack) with additional support costs, so I would like to see if someone has a better solution?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224031/Passing-Parameters-to-a-Running-Application-in-WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is how to do it when the application is already started?

Then you need a way of communicating with the already running app.

There are various ways of communicating between processes on a machine. One of them is to use named pipes.

You could for example you set up a single pipe server and one or more pipe clients and communicate between them by serializing data to and reading and deserializing data from a stream. There is an example of how to implement protocol activation of a running WPF app using this approach available [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/05/10/handle-protocol-activation-and-redirection-in-packaged-apps/) if you're interested in details.

The sample code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mgnsm/CodeSamples/tree/master/ActivationAndRedirectionSample).